# Why can I not connect to a Pervasive database with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, pervasive

I have a problem with my connection of symphony and Pervasive Database. When I try to connect to Pervasive, I get an error:

> Open database \symfonia\demo_fk\06config.dat. Error nr 3012: Error undocumented

Why can I not connect?

Answer (score 0):

A 3012 error means:

> 3012: Local engine is not accessible to the MicroKernel router Access
>   to the local engine is not possible because it is not loaded or could
>   not be launched. You can receive this status code if you try to access
>   a local file on a client and you do not have a Workgroup engine
>   installed or if you try to access a local file on a server and the
>   Server engine is not running.

Usually this occurs when a program tries to access a file on a machine that does not have a Pervasive engine installed.  Make sure that your database points to the proper location of the data files.